# Is it possible to use PassportJS without a local database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have an app that uses all of the oAuth authentications that are bundled with passport, but I'm using an external service for my database / user creation.

If I do something like this:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true        },
    function(req, username, password, done) {

        request.post('http://myapiservice.com/createuser').then(function(err,  response, body){
          return done(err, body.user); 
       })

    }))
```

How would I use a remotely-stored user with this? I'm not connecting to the database in any way other than a POST API call to create the user and a GET call to retrieve the user, so I'm not sure how Express' `req.user` would behave / get updated.

Can't find a single guide or question about this elsewhere so would love a bit of guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.user` will be populated by whatever you are "returning" as second argument by calling the `done` callback of the strategy. In your example code, that would be `body.user`.

It's perfectly legal to authenticate a user whichever way you want, and your code example seems legit enough (provided that you didn't mean to *create* a user from the strategy callback, but authenticate one using that remote API (see explanation below)).

One thing to consider is that the strategy callback isn't the only place where user data gets "looked up", that also happens inside the `passport.deserializeUser()` callback, which gets called for every route that you want authenticated.

It's up to you to decide how much user information you want to store in a session (this is what `serializeUser()` does). Storing more information means that you don't have to call the remote API for `deserializeUser()`, but it also means that any locally stored (in the session) user data may be out of sync with the remote API (if that can happen).

**EDIT**: regarding creating users in strategy callbacks: this isn't illegal, but it depends on the type of strategy if it's recommended.

For strategies that implement authentication against a remote service, like `passport-facebook`, it's common to create or update users from the strategy callback, because that's the only entry point where you receive the information from the remote service.

However, in your situation, and with `passport-local` in general, you should probably only use the strategy callback to authenticate, because you won't always have access to all the user information that you may need to create a new user.

It's better to create a separate Express route to which a create-user-form is posted, which will take care of creating the user (either in a local database or with a remote service, like in your case).

Comment: I *do* want to create a user with the request POST from the code snippet above. Is that not possible? Is there something special I'd have to do with `express-session` to get persistent logins to work?

Comment: @Jascination I edited my answer to explain a bit more about creating users. Feel free to ignore me though, nothing is set in stone here =D

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. One final thing, if I'm NOT using the strategy callback to create a user, what am I meant to pass back to `done(err, user)` ?

Comment: You're meant to look up a user in the strategy callback and "return" the user data using `done()`. See [_"Strategies"_](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure).